# Android Disable Drawertoggle Actionbar padding

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]

As you can see by the image the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is pushing the `ActionBar` to the right. I am using a custom view for inside the `ActionBar`
`ActionBar.setCustomView(View view);` so it is not as easy as just setting the `ActionBar` color. Somehow I need to make it so the toggle does not push the bar to the right.

And here is some code for the toggle:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mainView, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name){

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        }
    };;

    mainView.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to make this happen with my project either. My work around was to set a negative paddingLeft on my title textView. Something around 4-8 should be good.

Comment: Good idea. I just ended up creating a custom view and animating the slider myself via ondrawerslide